# How to minimize total sum of values in pandas dataframe under additional requirements

Tags: python, pandas, mathematical-optimization, driving-distance

via Google Distance Matrix API I am able to caclulate all driving times in seconds between addresses of each of my personnel and each of my customers (fake data in this example). I put this into a pivoted dataframe after calculating it. So now I have on the x-axis all the customers, on the y-axis all my personnel while the driving time in seconds are the values in the cells (The data is of course also available unpivoted with customers and personnel in a column each and the driving time in another column).

Now I want to calculate the optimal allocation of my personnel to the customers, thus minimizing the seconds of driving time over all. Important requirement: Certain customers need 2, other customers need 3 personnel assigned. 1 Personnel can only ever be allocated to 1 customer tho (that is referenced in the column "Versorgung".)

I am sure there is a mathematic solution to it but I just can't figure out how to solve it. Thank you in advance.

**Dataframe (unpivoted)**
[image]

**Pivoted Dataframe with seconds of driving time as values**
[image]

Comment: The best thing to do (IMHO) is to first write down a mathematical model for the problem. That is more precise than a piece of text. After that, the implementation and choosing an appropriate solver is not very difficult. At first sight. this looks to me like an assignment problem.

Comment: Thank you @ErwinKalvelagen! I wrote it down as a mathematical problem and solved it with PULP in Python.